# Count the unique values in R

Tags: r

Let say I have a dataset which is
Name     value
Ray        1
Allen      2
James      3
Curry      2
Erving     2

How can I count the unique values so that it returns
value   count
1:        1
2:        3
3:        1

Comment: could you please put your dataset here with dput()?

Comment: Use table(value)